# Breadth first Search Python Program Error : Key Error 3

Tags: python, algorithm

[image]I have written following python program to perform a BFS for the given graph, but after execution it gives the error : **Key Error 3**. What is wrong in my code?

```
output=[]
graph = {
            1:[2,3,4],
            2:[5,6],
            5:[9,10],
            4:[7,8],
            7:[11,12]
        }

def bfs(graph,root):
    queue = []
    visited=set()

    queue.append(root)
    visited.add(root)
    output.append(str(root))

    while not(queue==[]):
        for item in graph[root]:
            if item not in visited:
                queue.append(item)
                output.append(str(item))
                visited.add(item)
        root=queue.pop(0)

bfs(graph,1)
print(" ".join(output))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding nodes to your queue to search from that aren't in `graph`, and not checking they're in `graph` before trying to look them up. You can fix this by rewriting your `while` loop as:

```
while not(queue==[]):
    for item in graph[root]:
        if item not in visited:
            if item in graph:
                queue.append(item)
            output.append(str(item))
            visited.add(item)
    root=queue.pop(0)
```

(Alternatively, you could pre-populate `graph` with all of the unused keys from 1-12 with an empty list as the value.)